# Activity losing focus due to another Activity in the same app vs a separate app / device interrupt

Tags: android, android-activity

I need to log an event only when the application as a whole has lost focus (such as an incoming call or the home key).

What is the best way to tell an Activity has been paused or stopped from an external event rather than another activity within the same app?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

when your activity stops you can check if your app is still on top in the `onStop()` method:

```
private boolean isAppOnTop(){
    ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(Service.ACTIVITY_SERVICE); 
    List<ActivityManager.RunningTaskInfo> tasks; 
    tasks = am.getRunningTasks(1); 
    RunningTaskInfo running = tasks.get(0);
    if(running.topActivity.getPackageName().equals("your.package.name")){
        return true;
    }
    else{
        return false;
    }
}
```

This method queries all running tasks first. In general the task which has focus is on top of the stack. Check if this task belongs to your package.

Comment: Thanks. This method is nice and works but we were reluctant to get_tasks manifest permission.

Comment: True, I forgot about that permission. Your solution looks promising. I gonna keep that in mind. It's always good to prevent unnecessary permissions.

Answer (score 1):

So along with Dennis' answer which is perfectly valid if you are willing to set the get_tasks permission we explored the following options (mostly based on setting some kind of flag when onstop/onpause is called):

- When starting a new activity. In the onStop method if the flag is set to true then the interrupt was caused by a new activity in the app.
- Have a global variable which counts active views. Increments on onStarts and decrements on onStops. If its 0 then we have no visible activities.
- onStart sets an active flag true for the activity. onStop sets the flag to false. (states can also be saved to prefs). When the activity loses focuses we can check all the flags.

Because the app is relatively simple we went for the first option.